# Как оптимизировать процесс упаковки битов в байты на python?

Tags: python

Дано: Длинная байтовая последовательность, количество байтов в которой кратно 8.

Необходимо: Из каждого байта выделить старший бит и получившуюся последовательность упаковать в новый массив в виде байтов.

Используемое решение:

```
import struct

bar = b'\xa0\x74\x80\x4a\xd0\x69\xd1\x2f' * 100000 
foo = [] 
for i in range(0, len(bar), 8): 
    temp = '' 
    for j in range(0, 8, 1): 
        temp += str((bar[i + j] >> 7) & 0b1) 
    foo.append(struct.pack('B', int(temp, 2)))
```

Проблема: Введение строковой переменной для сбора битов, как мне представляется, не лучшим образом влияет на время исполнения кода ввиду действительно большого количества данных (пример кода упрощен, в реальной задаче речь идет о гигабайтах информации).

Вопрос: Как это можно реализовать без "костыля" в виде строковой переменной для ускорения выполнения кода?

Comment: Если Вы знаете длину, то эффективнее работать с объектом `array` нужной длины, если не знаете, вероятно, обрабатывать кусочками `array`  некоторой длины. А добавлять по элементу в список вряд ли эффективно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

а почему бы не продолжить работать с числами?

```
foo = []
for i in range(0, len(bar), 8):
    temp = 0
    for j in range(8):
        temp = temp * 2 + (bar[i + j] >> 7 & 0b1)
    foo.append(temp)
```

ну или так:

```
foo = [sum((bar[i + j] >> 7 & 0b1) * 2**j for j in range(8)) for i in range(0, len(bar), 8)]
```

Comment: Используя вместо строковой переменной числовую удалось сократить время обработки тестового куска данных на 45%! Обойтись без буферной переменной как я уже понял тут не получится, да и для преобразования в байты все равно пришлось пользоваться запаковщиком struct. Но в целом результат устраивает. Спасибо!